# Declare class instance in @interface

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create variable of type `ViewController` which is imported at the beginning of .h file

KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController.h;


@interface KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer
{
    ViewController* mainViewController; // error: Unknown type name `ViewController`; did you mean `UIViewController`?
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat rotation;

@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController* mainViewController; // error: Unknown type name `ViewController`; did you mean `UIViewController`?

@end
```

I need these variables to be in header file as they must be accessible and assignable from outside the class.

Thanks

Edit:

Thanks to the responses. As suggested by lostInTransit, the error is happening due to importing `ViewController` from `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer` and `KTOneFignerRotationGestureRecognizer` from `ViewController`. As suggested, I changed the `#import "ViewController.h"` to `@class ViewController;` which removed the errors, but now my code is unusable.

The purpose of accessing `ViewController` was that I wanted to retrieve position of `ViewController` object from `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer` but the `@class` declaration won't allow me to access this variable. I'll demonstrate.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIView* pitchCircleView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* pitchCircleView;

@end
```

And I'm trying to retrieve it in:

KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.m

`float f = mainViewController.pitchCircleView.frame.origin.x;`

but it gives me error: `Property pitchCircleView cannot be found in forward class object ViewController`

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to fail. Hope your ViewController.h is reachable on the line #import "ViewController.h". Also, a clean build might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular dependencies, which you can avoid with the use of `@class` in header files and `#import` in implementation files, but fundamentally you have a design flaw.

Presumably your `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer` wants to tell `ViewController` that something has happened, and so you should be designing and using a protocol which can convey just that information via the delegate pattern.

The `ViewController` class can conform to that protocol and set itself as the delegate of the gesture recognizer.

This means that the gesture recognizer can then be used by *any* view controller that conforms to the protocol and not just `ViewController`, which promotes code re-use.

This is commonly done with Cocoa classes.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `@class` instead of `#import`. And then import in the implementation. You might be seeing this because of circular inclusions (i.e. your `ViewController` class imports `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer`) - cannot be certain till we see some code though.

Comment: Indeed circular import was the problem. However, this solves the symptoms but not the actual problem. Now the error's don't show up but I can't retrieve the variable. Is there any workaround you might know?

Comment: You need to use `@class ViewController` in the file `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.h`.

Comment: Yes, that removes the errors, but doesn't allow me to retrieve pithCircleView object from the class instance.

Comment: Have you added a `#import` for ViewController in your implementation file for `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer` ?